# Clicking a picture to save on own laptop (like downloading it!)

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like that when you click a picture in a html-page a window opens so that you can save the picture on your own Laptop/etc.

HTML:
...

...

JS:
function download() 
var picture = document.getElementById("picture");
???
}

Answer (score 2):

The most simple solution is to use `download` attribute on `<a>` element, which calls browser "Save" dialog window:

```
<a href="path/to/image.jpg" download>Download image</a>
```

But be aware that it is [not supported in some browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download).